# Convert minutes to full time C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I need convert **1815 minutes** to **30:15** (**30 hours and 15 minutes**)

Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: How do you mean "convert"? into what type?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`TimeSpan.FromMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx):

```
var result = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1815);
```

This will give you an object that you can use in different ways.
For example:

```
var hours = (int)result.TotalHours;
var minutes = result.Minutes;
```

Comment: What is the easiest way to get this into a string? If the minutes are 65, this would give us 1 and 5 or 1:5 which doesn't look right. I could do an if statement to check if minutes is less than 10 but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @chill182: `result.ToString()` should work. You could also customize that by using [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `result.ToString(@"hh\:mm");`

Answer (score 4):

you can use this function

```
//minutes to be converted (70minutes = 1:10 hours)
int totalminutes = 70;
//total hours
int hours = 70 / 60;
//total minutes
int minutes = 70 % 60;
//output is 1:10
var time = string.Format("{0} : {1}", hours, minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes)`, this will give you `TimeSpan`, after that you can check `TimeSpan.Hours` and `TimeSpan.Minutes` properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
        DateTime d = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToLongTimeString());
        Console.WriteLine(d.AddMinutes(1815).ToLongTimeString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the desired string

```
  public string GetTimeString(int durationInMinute)
  {
            TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(durationInMinute);

            if(timeSpan.Hours == 1 && timeSpan.Minutes == 1)
                return timeSpan.Hours + " Hour and " + timeSpan.Minutes + " Min";
            else if (timeSpan.Hours > 1 && timeSpan.Minutes > 1)
                return timeSpan.Hours + " Hours and " + timeSpan.Minutes + " Mins";
            else if (timeSpan.Hours > 1 && timeSpan.Minutes < 1)
                return timeSpan.Hours + " Hours";
            else if(timeSpan.Hours < 1 && timeSpan.Minutes > 1)
                return timeSpan.Minutes + " Mins";
            else if(timeSpan.Hours == 1 && timeSpan.Minutes > 1)
                return timeSpan.Hours + " Hour and " + timeSpan.Minutes + " Mins";
            else if (timeSpan.Hours == 1 && timeSpan.Minutes == 0)
                return timeSpan.Hours + " Hour";
            else if (timeSpan.Hours == 0 && timeSpan.Minutes == 1)
                return timeSpan.Minutes + " Min";
            else
                return timeSpan.Hours + " Hours and " + timeSpan.Minutes + " Mins";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In razor this line resolved my same situation

```
@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(@landing.Duration).Hours @R.Hour @TimeSpan.FromMinutes(@landing.Duration).Minutes @R.Minute
```

The Output with the resource file has given the formatted and cultural result like below

> 2 h 55 m => english
>
> 2 sa 55 dk => turkish
>
> 2 ora 55 min => italian

Answer (score 0):

I liked Giorgio's solution, I improved it some and wrapped it in an extension method

```
public static class ToStringFormatter
{
    public static string ToTimeString(this int totalminutes)
    {
        int hours = totalminutes / 60;
        //total minutes
        int minutes = totalminutes % 60;
        //output is 1:10
        var time = $"{hours}:{minutes:00}";
        return time;
    }
}
```